# If a picture is not in the desktop, how do I use it in pygame?

Tags: python

I am learning pygame and they said that my picture must be in the desktop in order to use the picture in pygame. However, I could not drag it to desktop. (for some administrative reasons) May I know if it is possible for pygame to access those files if my folder is on the desktop? The name of my folder is "UsedForPygame".

Comment: Please clarify this restriction.  Who made that requirement?  What happens when you simply use the file with its full path?

Comment: if you put images in folder with your code and you will start code in this folder then you can use only filenames. If you will start code from different place then it is better to use full path to images - `C:/full/path/to/UsedForPygame/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the full path. There are multiple ways to get absolute file paths in different operating systems:

For example:

1. On Windows, hold the Shift key and right-click on the image and then click on "Copy as path".
2. On Linux, just right-click on the image and click "copy".

Now get back to your code and paste the complete image path. Just to give you an example, the full path should look like "**C:\some\path\UsedForPygame\image.png**" on windows and "**/home/username/some/path/UsedForPygame/image.png**" in Linux.

To avoid username in Linux, you can replace "/home/username" with "~/", so your full path would look like "~/path/UsedForPygame/image.png".

Comment: The "on Linux" portion has some possibly unwarranted assumptions, starting with the one that you have a GUI and a mouse at all. Probably the instruction is specific to some particular desktop environment (Ubuntu? Gnome?)

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution would to get the path of the image or whatever you need.

Example: ***C:/User/Desktop...***

I don't usually use Windows so I don't know paths off the top of my head.
Additionally, you could try and put your pygame file and image into your same folder
and just get the name of your image/file.